# Anaconda did not install packages openpyxl and xlrd

Tags: python, pandas, module, conda

After installing a new Python 3.6 environment with pandas, numpy, etc. when I tried to use the following pandas method I got the following errors:

```
>>> df.to_excel(filename)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

Similar issue occurred earlier when I used the `pd.read_excel` method.

In both cases the problem was solved by installing `openpyxl` / `xlrd` with `conda install` but I would like to know if this is intentional behaviour and why openpyxl/xlrd wouldn't be considered a dependencies of pandas and installed from the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is intentional. If you read [the Optional Dependencies section of the Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#optional-dependencies), you can see that Excel I/O is included in there.

A couple arguments I can think of for why this is a good thing:

1. There are so many features incorporated into Pandas that including everything by default would really bloat installs.
2. There are multiple compatible alternatives for Excel I/O, so it may not be fair to impose a particular choice on people, especially if they already have one installed for another dependency.

However, I do think the error handling here could be improved. For example, it would have been better to provide a message saying that this functionality isn't available without one of the packages, rather than hitting a hard `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  I thought that might be the case and it does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, in my case the problem was not solved by Conda install for the missing dependency package, it was solved by pip install...`pip install xlrd`.

Comment: I followed your suggestion. It worked, at first, but when trying load an excel file, I got another error message: XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported