# pandas cannot read excel lack of xlrf

Tags: python, pandas, xlrd

My pandas cannot read xlsx:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path)
```

with error message:

`ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.`

I tried to install xlrd in Commond for all those case:`python3 -m pip install xlrd`, `pip install xlrd`, `pip3 install xlrd`

System showed It successful to install the xlrd (I also tried to delete and install again):

`Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in c:\users\<My system>\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (2.0.1)`

However I still had the same error. I also tried a alternative way:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path, engine= 'openpyxl')
```

exactly same error happened for `openpyxl` with `xlrd`.

Comment: You may be running pandas in a different environment from your system environment.

Comment: @ifly6 I guess so, do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Install `xlrd` in the appropriate environment.

Comment: try to `cd` to the location your python is in and then do the pip command from there.

Comment: @ifly6 could you give me a complete solution? I am totally new on this part.

Comment: I have no idea how you installed Python so I can't give you anything more specific.

Comment: how do you run script? if you run as `python script.py` then should work `python -m pip install xlrd`. But if you run script with different Python then you should use different Python also to install modules. Error shows `python39` so maybe you should install it with `python39 -m pip install ...` or `python3.9 -m pip install ...`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Would you know which python you are launching to run your pandas script? If it's anaconda, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55251162/anaconda-did-not-install-packages-openpyxl-and-xlrd#55252639

Answer (score 0):

Pandas used to require xlrd but not anymore.  xlrd >= 2.0 supports only xls format, not xlsx.  You could downgrade xlrd to 1.2, but I prefer using openpyxl.

Also, when reading xlsx, you may need to use pd.read_excel not pd.read_csv.  Here's an example of reading an xlsx file with openpyxl that works for me:

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, 'Sheet1', index_col=None, na_values=[""], na_filter=False,engine='openpyxl').astype(str)
```